# Entity framework + average part of column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core

I have a table like below in SQL Server

```
id       datetime           temperature
1     2020-01-1 10:00          22
2     2020-01-1 10:20          23
3     2020-01-1 10:40          27
4     2020-01-1 11:00          20
5     2020-01-1 11:20          19
6     2020-01-1 10:40          10
```

I want to create a query that averages for any one hour like below

```
id       datetime           temperature
1     2020-01-1 10:00          24        */ average for 10 o clock
2     2020-01-1 11:00        16.33       */ average for 11 o clock
```

Can anyone assist?

Comment: How can you calculate **(20 + 19) / 2 = 19.5** for *11:00* ?

Comment: The last entry (6) is probably 11:40, not 10:40

Comment: yes 11:40 is correct

Answer (score 0):

You can [`GroupBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.8) then use [`Average`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.average?view=netframework-4.8) to achieve it.

> Computes the average of a sequence of numeric values.

```
var result = dbContext.your_table.GroupBy(p => new { p.Id, p.datetime })
                        .Select(g => new
                         {
                             id = g.Keys.Id,
                             datetime = g.Keys.datetime,
                             temperature = g.Select(p => p.temperature).Average()
                         });
```